# Delete files with same size but keep always one file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-management, find

I have a directory full of zipfiles, that contain many files. They are created by software and this is currently not fixable. I tried to work with `fdupes`, but this process took too long, because there are about 50k files. I know that all files with the same size are duplicates without any exceptions.

So how could I now **delete all useless files?** I already got this command that prints me the files to keep, but I don't know how to convert this in a oneliner to use it as cronjob.

```
find . -type f -printf "%s %p\n" | grep "zip" | sort -n | uniq -d --check-chars=10
```

---

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 14:40 save_2016-04-22-14_40_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 14:45 save_2016-04-22-14_45_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 14:50 save_2016-04-22-14_50_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 14:55 save_2016-04-22-14_55_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:00 save_2016-04-22-15_00_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:05 save_2016-04-22-15_05_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:10 save_2016-04-22-15_10_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:15 save_2016-04-22-15_15_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:20 save_2016-04-22-15_20_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:25 save_2016-04-22-15_25_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:30 save_2016-04-22-15_30_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:35 save_2016-04-22-15_35_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:40 save_2016-04-22-15_40_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:45 save_2016-04-22-15_45_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:50 save_2016-04-22-15_50_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2550472 Apr 22 15:55 save_2016-04-22-15_55_01.zip #keep
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2556836 Apr 22 16:00 save_2016-04-22-16_00_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2556836 Apr 22 16:05 save_2016-04-22-16_05_01.zip #keep
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2586848 Apr 22 16:10 save_2016-04-22-16_10_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2586848 Apr 22 16:15 save_2016-04-22-16_15_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2586848 Apr 22 16:20 save_2016-04-22-16_20_01.zip #keep
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2590213 Apr 22 16:25 save_2016-04-22-16_25_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2590213 Apr 22 16:30 save_2016-04-22-16_30_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2590213 Apr 22 16:35 save_2016-04-22-16_35_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2590213 Apr 22 16:40 save_2016-04-22-16_40_01.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2590213 Apr 22 16:45 save_2016-04-22-16_45_01.zip #keep
```

The command above prints something like that:

```
2590215 ./save_2016-04-25-14_20_01.zip
2590216 ./save_2016-04-25-14_00_01.zip
2590259 ./save_2016-05-17-13_10_01.zip
2590278 ./save_2016-05-17-13_35_01.zip
2590286 ./save_2016-05-17-13_50_01.zip
2590291 ./save_2016-05-17-14_25_01.zip
2590294 ./save_2016-05-17-13_55_01.zip
```

Any Ideas? I have also no rights to install more software, only the commands are available as for Ubuntu server 14.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the command which files to keep, you can combine this with the move command `mv`. Just move them to another folder (ore give them another prefix), delete the remaining files and move them back.

Take a look at the `-t` parameter of `mv`. You can use this to specify the destination and then pipe multiple files to mv.

Comment: I've edited my question, but as you say, I could get rid of the filesize, and than pipe that list to a `mv`

Comment: yes. The command would be `| grep -o "./.*"` (assuming your file name will never contain a "/")

Comment: I just added this `| awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs mv -t final/` and it worked. thanks.

Comment: awk is also fine, I am just not very familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for the grep - I always use grep for splitting rows and awk for splitting columns. Pretty easy and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

It may be not vital, but you should be aware that two zips may be different even if their sizes in bytes are equal. If you wish to get rid of the danger this holds, you can check the md5sum of the files. It is still not a 100% guarantee to delete only duplicates but your chances are far better.

This is one way to do it using awk to send the filenames to xargs for deletion (sample with my files):

```
$ ls -l [a-d][1-3].txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 2 May 27 16:39 a1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 3 May 27 16:39 a2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 4 May 27 16:39 a3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 2 May 27 16:39 b1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 3 May 27 16:39 b2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 4 May 27 16:39 b3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 2 May 27 16:39 c1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 3 May 27 16:39 c2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 4 May 27 16:39 c3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 2 May 27 16:39 d1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 3 May 27 16:39 d2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 4 May 27 16:39 d3.txt
$ md5sum [a-d][1-3].txt | sort -k1 | awk '$1==prevsum {print $2}; {prevsum=$1}' | xargs  rm
$ ls -l [a-d][1-3].txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 2 May 27 16:39 a1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 3 May 27 16:39 a2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lx lx 4 May 27 16:39 a3.txt
```

Since I don't care about the file sizes and I do know the naming pattern of the files, I don't even have to use find.

Comment: Yes this would be better, but I know that my files are always different on byte sizes. This is because each zip contains a specific filetree, and 1 or 2 files get bigger - that's it. I wanted it to get as fast as possible done, because the machine isn't that powerful. Even md5 checking would take far too long ;)